# Image Similarity with Resnet152 Embeddings Pretrained with Imagenet

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to find similar images given a source image. I'm doing this taking a Resnet152 model pretrained on the Imagenet dataset. I was trying to replace the last layer (which was a fully connected layer with a softmax activation) with a `Flatten` layer in order to get a vector describing the image.

I have a [working demo](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1862aGHz2_Ir_icOEBsARicL_7zl10rO9), but it's not working as expected. I can get the outputs of different images, but when I calculate the difference between two images of cats, vs an image of a cat and an image of a dog, they don't match. It seems to be indifferent of the image. I've tried with different images having the same result.

Am I missing something? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I noticed that you get different distances, so I am not sure about your statement `I've tried with different images having the same result.` I would suggest testing same image, this should give you 0 distance, right? and it will help you eliminate options of why this is happening.

Comment: @AhmadBaracat I am getting distances indeed. However, they don't make sense. When I compare two images of cats, they should be closer than an image of a cat and an image of a car. The model seem to be indifferent of which image I feed. That's the main problem.

Comment: I see, have you tried the test I suggested (i.e. feed the same image twice)?

Comment: @AhmadBaracat I have. I noticed that one of the methods I was using was giving nonsense. The other ones are giving 0 distance between the same image. However, they are also giving the same distance for two different car images vs a car and a dog, which makes no sense as well.

Comment: Ok great, now keep using the ones giving you 0 distance, can you try fixing image1 (ex: cat), then try for example 20 other images (cats, dogs, cars, etc.) and plot the images and distances with respect to that image1?